# Which comic issue does Superman fight someone powered by prayer?

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman

I read a comic once, long since given away, where Superman fought someone who was powered by prayer, without using force.

I'm hazy on the details, and there wasn't much to the story besides the 'powered by prayer' conceit.

I read it some ~7-8 years ago, and it was current at the time because it was part of a Sci-Fi Stack Exchange comic books giveaway (sadly discontinued).

I would like to be able to reference that issue when discussing how Superman's superlative abilities reduce his problems down to moral problems, but I've long since forgotten the series and issue number.

When did he fight a human who was powered by prayer?

Comment: Can you remember any of the plot or anything about this beyond the opponent?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot there was very little plot at all. Someone was causing trouble, he was powered by the prayers of his church community, and superman managed to defeat him but I forget how besides he didn't use force.

Comment: So not Superman #40? https://screenrant.com/superman-weakness-prayer-religion-powers/

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no not that one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Action Comics Vol. 1* Issue 848](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_848) and likely [the following issue](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_849) which continues the storyline "Redemption - In Good Faith". In it the villain would be [Redemption](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Jarod_Dale_(New_Earth)).

[image: Redemption hovers in the sky; the locals say "they believe in Redemption" whilst Redemption says "I answer to a higher authority" and the local militia try to kick him out]

Comment: FWIW I remembered this from [this answer of mine](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/218646/58193).